# Does the Heroes Handbook suggest that constructs should get an alternate save for Affects Objects?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e, constructs

In 3E, much as in 2E, Constructs are generally built with absent Stamina, much like objects, with Immunity (Fortitude) protecting them from most attacks that would target Stamina, like poison gas or suffocation.

The Affects Objects modifier allows one to take an attack that normally targets Fortitude, and allows it to work automatically against non-living objects with them automatically failing, to model normally fort-based effects like Weaken or Affliction, for example acid attacks, to not only work against objects, but at full power.

The issue here is whether constructs are intended to always suffer this worst possible result, or if the intent is for them to simply use an alternate save.

I remember that, back in the day, Steve Kenson suggested that GMs allow constructs, particularly those run by PCs to make a save against Toughness instead, so that a 30 PP Immunity (Fortitude) power wasn't eliminated entirely by a +0 to +1 Extra, and I could have sworn that 3E made this more explicit to allow for an alternate save rather than the effect just bypassing all defenses, but now I can't find that line in the online SRD or my books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in the *Heroes Handbook*, but [I asked in the March 28, 2022 M&M Monday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbhFEhWoZEQ) whether Affects Objects should just change the save type against Constructs, and Steve replied:

> When you're dealing Constructs as characters, that should usually be the case.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that modifier was developed thinking on static objects, like a chair, a weapon, armor, etc. Something that cannot move by itself.

The description states that, by GM rules, someone holding, carrying, or wearing an object could make a Dodge save to avoid the effect. So I think it's fair to assume that a Construct, capable of moving (like a character usually does), can make the same move to avoid the effect.

Constructs description also says that they are like Minions - a character -, not Devices or regular equipment. Seems appropriate to me that they can make a Dodge save in this case.